# Split a Number into multiple numbers with an increasing pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math

Hopefully I make sense. I want something like this.

Consider, **Total = 10**

**I want to divide Total into 5 parts**

```
[n,n,n,n,n]
```

*(If we add all numbers in this array it results to 10 )*

---

Now suppose the **increment pattern is Step = 2%**

So it should be like

```
[n, n + 2%, n + 4%, n + 6%, n + 8%]
```

*(adding all should result to 10)*

I found this answer, but unable to add the increment pattern -
[Split number into 4 random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405397/split-number-into-4-random-numbers)

Comment: This seems like a high school algebra problem.

Comment: What does this have to do with random numbers? You just need to solve a linear equation.

Comment: The number can be divided into random numbers that add up to be 10

Comment: To do something like this, you would need to do some algebra and output an answer. Right now, you cannot do algebra in JS, so you could possibly use an API.

Comment: But they're not random numbers. You have to find the specific number `n` that solves the equation. `n*1 + n*1.02 + n*1.04 + n*1.06 + n*1.08 = total`

Comment: Solve that equation for `n` and you'll have the formula you need.

Comment: Yeah that sounds right, maybe I can find a single number N to solve this.
Sounds easy now... Thanks

Comment: If you ever asked your math teacher "Why do I need to learn algebra?", now you know.

Comment: haha yeah, thanks @Barmar

Comment: If you want, you could add it as an answer :) @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an array of numbers that satisfies the pattern.

```
var xs = [1, 1.02, 1.04, 1.06, 1.08]
```

Find the total of those.

```
var total = 0;
xs.forEach(x => total += x)
```

Get the ratio between that and your desired total.

```
var scale = 10 / total
```

Multiply your numbers by the scale and they will sum to 10.

```
var result = xs.map(x => x * scale)
```

Comment: You're a  Legend

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple algebra problem to solve.

`n + X%` is equivalent to `n * (1 + X/100)`, so your sequence is:

```
n + n*1.02 + n*1.04 + n*1.06 + n*1.08 = total
// Use the distributive rule of addition over multiplication
n*(1 + 1.02 + 1.04 + 1.06 + 1.08) = total
// Simplify the sum in parentheses
n*5.20 = total
// Divide both sides by 5.20
n = total/5.20
```

Once you have `n` you can use a `for` loop to create the resulting array.

```
result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    result.push(n * (1 + 0.2*i));
}
```